bazel query ignore all **/.cache/**/BUILD files
I want to execute bazel query //... but I have many .cache folders in my repo and they may contain BUILD files in their subfolders that may cause bazel errors. I want bazel to exclude all BUILD files that matches the glob pattern **/.cache/**/BUILD. What should I do?
In the documentation, I find that filter can be used for filtering basing on the name of the target, but that is after parsing BUILD files which cannot prevent errors.
Also, it seems that .bazelignore cannot ignore .cache folder in subfolders. (see this open issue)
Minimal setup:
.
├── .cache
│   └── BUILD  # garbage file
└── BUILD      # normal file

Running bazel query //... gives errors as the BUILD file in .cache is invalid.

Are you able to add BUILD files to the .cache directories?
That might make you able to more easily exclude them. That thread is very closely related to this question.

@Kip Yes. I could use a bash script to enumerate the cache directories and add build files.
